# R fill columns n times

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Hi I want to simulate a dataset like this:

```
City    Person
  1        1          
  1        2
  1        3
  2        1
  2        2
  2        3
```

Where City ID can go from 1-30 and Person ID from 1-40. I know that I can create City by the following code:

```
data=data.frame(City=rep(1:30,40),Person=0)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to assign the Person variable for each City ID without using a loop. How do I assign the Person IDs from 1-40 for each City ID? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with

```
df1$Person <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(City), City, FUN = seq_along))
```

Or

```
df1$Person <- sequence(table(df1$City))
```

---

Also, an easier expansion would be

```
expand.grid(City = 1:30, Person = 1:3)
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(City = 1:30, Person = 1:3)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   group_by(City) %>%
   mutate(Person = row_number())
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Person := seq_len(.N), by = City]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(City = rep(1:2, each = 3))
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I will accept this as the answer once the system lets me.